# prevent the terminal from closing when the custom bash function is run

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote the following program in my linux bashrc

```
open()
{
  echo enter file name
  read fname
  locate $fname> /home/vvajendla/Desktop/backup/loc;
  cat loc
  exec < /home/vvajendla/Desktop/backup/loc;
  value=0
  while read line
  do
    value=`expr $value + 1`;
    echo $value 
    echo $line
    if [ $value -le 6 ]
    then
      gedit $line;
    else 
      echo too many files to open
    fi 
  done
```

}

The above function searches all the directories for the file-string match and opens them using GEDIT if they are less than or equal to 6.

whenever i run this function in the terminal,it gets closed.
Can you please tell me what i can do to keep it open?

Answer (score 3):

The `exec` causes the standard input of the calling shell to be permanently redirected from the file.  Once the file closes, the shell runs out of input, and exits.  I assume you import this function with `source`; running it standalone should work.

The usual way to write this sort of function would be to make it accept an argument, so you would invoke it like "open fnord" instead of run "open" and enter "fnord" at the prompt.

```
open () {
  local fname
  fname=$1            # notice this arrangement instead of read
  local value
  value=0

  locate "$fname" |   # notice double quotes
  tee /dev/stderr |   # as a superior alternative to using a temporary file
  while read line
  do
    value=`expr $value + 1`
    if [ $value -le 6 ]
    then
      gedit "$line"  # notice double quotes
    else 
      echo too many files to open >&2  # notice redirection to stderr
    fi 
  done

}
```

The diagnostic is misleading; this code will still open the first six files, then bail with an error message at the seventh.  Is that what you intend?  Or should it count the number of outputs, and refuse to run if there are more than six?

If you don't care for the other improvements, the minimal fix is to remove the `exec` and read the `while` loop's input from your temporary file.  (You should take care to properly clean up; if you can avoid a temporary file, that's basically always a better solution.)

```
while read line; do
    ....
done <tempfile
```

I would be tempted to add line numbers with `nl` to get rid of the unattractive `expr`, but this might break file names with a space at the beginning.  (On the other hand, `locate` always produces a full path name, right?)

As an alternative, and assuming `gedit` can read multiple file name arguments, try this:

```
locate "$fname" | head -n 6 | xargs gedit
```

This fails to produce a warning if there are more than six files, but I would actually consider that a feature.